# AFNetworking iOS HTTP Long Polling

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking

Trying to implement a long-polling implementation in Objective-C using the `AFNetworking` library. However, am not sure that I am doing it right.

Basically am creating a GET request:
    `NSError *error = nil;`

```
NSDictionary *queryParams = nil;
if ([parameters objectForKey:@"timestamp"]) {
    queryParams = @{@"timestamp" : [parameters objectForKey:@"timestamp"]};
}

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [self.requestSerializer requestWithMethod:@"GET" URLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@sample/%@/state", self.baseURL.absoluteString, [parameters objectForKey:@"sampleKey"]] parameters:queryParams error:&error];
[request setTimeoutInterval:50];
[request setValue:[parameters objectForKey:@"currentSessionToken"] forHTTPHeaderField:kAuthenticationHeaderField];

return [self APIOperationWithRequest:request willRetry:NO success:^(NSDictionary *JSON) {
    success(JSON);
} failure:^(NSDictionary *errorResponseDict) {
    failure(errorResponseDict);
}];
```

and whether it times out or is a success, I recreate the operation and put it again in the operation queue.

Is this ok as a method or would there be a better way of implementing this? Would be helpful if I could find more detailed resources on this.

Comment: That's a good approach. Here you have a good article on AFNetworking by his creator: http://nshipster.com/afnetworking-2/